# jqGrid. if event onSortComplete is available?

Tags: jquery, events, jqgrid, callback

Im trying to figure out, if some event like 'onSortComplete' is available for this plugin. jqGrid already have event 'onSortCol', which is raised BEFORE sorting of some particular column, and it is not suitable for me.
I have already tried to use event 'gridComplete' to work around this, but this event is raised   almost on after each action with grid. (e.g. adding new Row).

Does anybody have any solutions?

---

Thanks in advance, Ivan.

Answer (score 1):

If sorting is started the grid contain will be reloaded from the server or from the local data. So the end of sorting is after the grid will be loaded and filled. So the usage of `loadComplete` or `gridComplete` is the correct way. If you need distinguish between end of sorting and other refreshing of the grid you can just set a variable inside of `onSortCol` which you clear always in `loadComplete` or `gridComplete`. In the way you would be able to do some actions at the end of sorting.

Comment: Thank you, surely its a solution. But it will be good to use some 'native' implementation of callback for such event.

Comment: @Johnny: Sorry, what you mean under 'native' implementation? I still not understand why you need have `onSortComplete` and which actions you want to do inside. An example can clear all. If you have an feature request you should post it to Tony Tomov (the developer of jqGrid) in the [trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/). On the stackoverflow other users can help you to use existing functionality of jqGrid.

Comment: Yep, native its officially supported by plugin. Inside this callback, I want to redraw some data on the page, which depends on the order of grid elements.

Comment: @Johnny: As I wrote before, to have "native" support you should place the feature request. I recommend you to describe an example which shows advantages of the introduction of the new event/callback. You current explanation "I want to redraw some data on the page, which depends on the order of grid elements" help me not understand your problem. Additionally I don't see here any relation to the sorting of data.